# Как сделать так, чтобы выбранный при помощи input type="file" файл открывался на другой странице при нажатии на input type="submit"?

Tags: веб-программирование

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, у меня есть такой код:

```
<form action="Copery_second.html">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" >
  <input type="submit" value="Загрузить">
</form>
```

При нажатии на submit осуществляется переход на другую страницу. Как сделать так, чтобы выбранный при помощи `input type="file"` файл при нажатии на submit запускался на другой странице.
Начал учить js, чтобы решить ее, но самостоятельно, думаю решить не смогу.

Comment: *столкнулся со следующей проблемой: у меня есть следующий код:..* Я, конечно, извиняюсь, а где собственно сам код? И что это за скриншот? Как он относится к вопросу? Приведите, пожалуйста, [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, забыл добавить код.

Comment: Я надеюсь, что объяснил все доходчиво

Comment: Полагаю, для вашей задачи нужно использовать PHP. Действия примерно такие: по нажатию на кнопку файл сохраняется на сервере, при прогрузке `Copery_second.html` в соответствующее место php-вставочкой подставляется ссылка на файл (если речь про картинку, то в атрибут `src`).

Comment: Нельзя ли сделать все это на Python?